# can we convert one class data into another class by operator overloading in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have 2 classes `Employee` and `Person`. Employee class  have three attributes `name`, `age` and `salary`. Person class have attributes `name` and `age`. I want to overload assignment operator to assign name and age of Employee class to name and age person class.

```
class Employee {
    string name;
    int age;
    float salary;
public:
    Employee()
    {
        name="";
        age=0;
        salary=0;

    }
    void operator =(const Employee& a)
    {
        name=a.name;
        age=a.age;
    }

};

class Person {
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person()
    {
        name="";
        age=0;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Name are :"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Age are  :"<<age<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employee obj;
    person obj1;
    obj=obj1;     
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Have you tried? You have already written an assignment operator for `Employee` that takes an `Employee` argument; now you need one for `person` that takes an `Employee` argument. You can olso look into **casting operators.**

Comment: how do we casting operator?

Comment: see also:   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

Comment: A casting operator looks like `Employee::operator person() const {...};`

Comment: but the link mention above which is not helpful for me because they explain for same classes object but we use assignment operator for different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the answer of above Questions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    float salary;

public:

    // default constructor (meaning less) 
    Employee() {
        name   =   "";
        age    =   0;
        salary =   0.0;
    }

    // Parameterized constructor
    Employee(string name, int age, float salary) {
        this->name   = name;
        this->age    = age;
        this->salary = salary;
    }

    // getter members to
    // get value of private members
    // from outside class
    string getName() {
        return this->name;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return this->age;
    }

    float getSalary() {
        return this->salary;
    }
    };
   class Person: Employee {
    private:
    string name;
    int age;
    public:
    Person() {
        name = "";
        age  = 0;
    }

    void operator = (Employee &emp) {
        this->name = emp.getName();
        this->age  = emp.getAge();
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "Name is : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Age is  : " << age << endl;
    }
}; 
int main() {
Employee emp("Emp", 25, 45000.00);
Person p1;

p1 = emp;
p1.display();
return 0;
```

}